# Why do I get an error when trying to use a method in application_controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, class, methods, controller

In my Ruby on Rails application I have a cinema application and am trying to populate a drop down menu with films that have showing dates that are not in the past.

In my _form.html.erb I have this dropdown menu that is trying to use the `live_films` method:

```
<%= f.grouped_collection_select :showing_id, Film.order(:title).live_films, :showings, :title, :id,  :showing_times %>
```

The method is in application_controller:

```
helper_method :active_menu, :live_films 

def live_films 
    Film.includes(:showings).where.not(showings.show_date < Date.today)
end
```

I also suspect that my method wouldn't work so I welcome suggestions for getting it to function.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It looks like you want a named scope on the `Film` model then you can chain the order to the method http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be calling `order` on result of `live_films` method call as:

```
<%= f.grouped_collection_select :showing_id, live_films.order(:title), :showings, :title, :id,  :showing_times %>
```

Comment: Thank you! That's worked! How would you recommend sorting out the method so that it does not show dates that are in the past, `showings.show_date < Date.today`, does  not work.

Comment: Try: `Film.includes(:showings).where('showings.show_date > ?', Date.current.beginning_of_day)`.  Note that using `Date.today` returns system date without considering Rails time zone.  Use `Date.current` to make the date  timezone aware.

Comment: That causes this error: `SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: showings.show_date: SELECT "films".* FROM "films" WHERE (showings.show_date > '2015-02-19 00:00:00.000000')  ORDER BY "films"."title" ASC`

Comment: @benjs.1, is the error resolved?  Use appropriate column name for `show_date`, I copied the table name and column name from your question.

Comment: No I still have the error, that is the correct table and column name

Comment: It doesn't even like this: `Film.includes(:showings).where('showings.id > 5')` shows the error `no such column: showings.id`

Comment: Why isn't there a join in the query.  You do have `includes(:showings)` in your query don't you.  Also, can  you check to make sure the `has_many` and `belongs_to` are setup correctly in these two models.

Comment: The film `has_many` showings and the showings `belongs_to` film is there, I have `includes(:showings)`, how would I do the join?

Comment: Can you post a new question showing the association and that your promlematic query?

Comment: I can't post anther question for another hour yet